# Observable override toString()

Tags: javascript, select, knockout.js, tostring, observable

I am binding a KnockoutJS observable (which is keeping track of a whole Object) to a select tag with the 'value' binding and I was wondering if it's possible to somehow get a text representation of that selected Observable?

Here is an example object that I am binding to

```
var dogObject = ko.observable({
   Property1 = ko.observable(),
   Property2 = ko.observable(),
   .
   .
   .
})
```

And here is the select tag:

```html
<select class="textbox" data-bind="options: collectionOfDogObjects(), optionsCaption: 'Select...', optionsValue: $data, optionsText: 'Property1', value: dogObject"</select>
```

Comment: Include some code. What does you view model look like? What does your binding look like? Have you read the knockout docs?

Comment: Take a look at [computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) - you can write one that will return a text representation of the object in your observble and update anything bound to it when the underlying things change.  Or make an observable property on your object itself, again possibly computed if necessary.

Comment: @MattBurland Yes, I have read the documentation. And Since I couldn't find a solution which would fit my requirements, I posted a question here.

Comment: @JamesThorpe is spot on (should probably turn that comment into an answer). Currently you have `Property1` as the textual representation of an object, at least in the context of your `select`, you could introduce an `AsText` computed observable to take over that feature.

Comment: @Jeroen I'm back in the middle of stuff at the mo - feel free, you'll get my vote...!

Comment: @Jeroen I sure will after I confirm it and test it out.

Answer (score 1):

The option to do this you've already included in your code: use `optionsText` to specify which property *is* the toString representation of the object.

You have very little code in your question, but it appears you're currently using just one of the observables. If you mean to create a `toString` that combines several, you could consider using a computed observable. This is easiest if you have proper view models with constructor functions or some other form of inheritance. Here's an example:

```js
var Dog = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.Property1 = ko.observable(data.p1);
  self.Property2 = ko.observable(data.p2);
  self.toString = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.Property1() + " " + self.Property2();
  });
};

ko.applyBindings({
  collectionOfDogObjects: ko.observableArray([
    new Dog({ p1: "German", p2: "Shephard" }),
    new Dog({ p1: "Russian", p2: "Snowdog" })
  ]),
  dogObject: ko.observable(null)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: collectionOfDogObjects(), optionsCaption: 'Select...', optionsValue: $data, optionsText: 'toString', value: dogObject"></select>
```